# _http_server.js - no request('events') yet .emit() && .on() how?

Tags: javascript, node.js

_http_server.js on github at /nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js uses the .emit() Method 14 times, plus it uses the .on() Method 11 times.

I am confused because I believe this method comes from request('events') in Node.js. I searched for a such in the entire file and this line has been commented out from Line 113 to Line 130. I can find no other way for the .emit() and .on() Methods to be used.

Could anyone explain how it is possible to use both the .emit() and the .on() without request('events')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[_http_server.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.9.2/lib/_http_server.js) uses `EventEmitter` (what you get from `require('events')`) through [**inheritance**](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor).

- The `ServerResponse` [inherits from `OutgoingMessage`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.9.2/lib/_http_server.js#L97), which [inherits from `Stream`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.9.2/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L88), which in turn [inherits from `EventEmitter`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.9.2/lib/stream.js#L8).
- The `Server` itself [inherits from `net.Server`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.9.2/lib/_http_server.js#L250), which [inherits from `EventEmitter`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.9.2/lib/net.js#L1146).

This is why _http_server.js is able to use `EventEmitter` methods even though you don't see `require('events')` in that file: the classes it depends on ultimately depend on `EventEmitter`.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand; net.Server inherits from EventEmitter, and Server then inherits EventEmitter because by inheritance IE net.Server 'passes' EventEmitter to server.